# Install Framework Phalcon PHP in Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: phalcon

how to install phalcon php in Windows?

I installed wamp and followed the manual from the official page but I couldn't

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Be sure correct versión of dll to download:
   [php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzAo9.png)
2. be sure the phalcon dll you need.[PHalcon DLL](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/releases/tag/v5.1.2)
3. Stop Wamp.
4. Edit php.ini and insert "extension=php_phalcon.dll"
5. Restart WAMP

Comment: And 6. If installing Phalcon 4.1.2, don't forget to install `php-psr.dll`